# AJAX / PHP - Get specific data back from POST (Pass data)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax post that looks like this: (Located in: `post.php`)

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'prize.php',
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function(req) {
                    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8');
                },
                data: {sw: screen.width, sh: screen.height, saw:screen.availWidth, sah: screen.availHeight, scd: screen.colorDepth, tz: (new Date().getTimezoneOffset()), bp: sbp, hf: have_flash},
                success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {

                if(data=="success"){

                        $('#status').text("You won: $<?php echo $data['prize'] ?>!");


                }else {
                   $("#m_error_msg").html(data);
                 }


                },error: function (){
                }
                });
```

The above ajax call, posts to this page: `prize.php` That looks like this:

```
if($_POST){
  $data = array("data"=>"success","code"=>"100","prize"=>"$prize","type"=>"$text");
  die($data['data']);
}
```

My question is.. How can I pass the `$data['prize']` or `$data['type']` to the:

```
if(data=="success"){}
```

code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `dataType:'json'` to your `$.ajax()` handler to declare you wish to receive a `json encoded` result back from the server:

```
type: "POST",
url: 'prize.php',
cache: false,
dataType:'json',
```

Then in your response from the server, send back a `json_encoded`ed array.

```
echo json_encode($data);
die();
```

Then in your success function, let's check:

```
success: function(data){
    if(data.data == 'success'){

    }
}
```